# Not able to query data with special character in hive or Presto

Tags: hive, hiveql, presto

Data is residing in parquet format. Parquet support the column name to have '[' bracket. Also able to create the table in hive with same column name. But select of column is failing.

Is there any way to handle special character '[]' in column name in hive or Presto?

Answer (score 3):

You can use double-quote on Presto and back-quote on Hive:

```sql
-- Presto
SELECT 1 as "[name]"

-- Hive
SELECT 1 as `[name]`
```

Comment: This does not work as column name have special character '[' hence back tick or quote does not work.

Comment: Could you share the actual column name?

Comment: Let's say abc[xyz]mnq is the column name. DDL works fine when I created table but select is not working.

Comment: It should be accessible even with SELECT. At least, I can access the hive parquet table using the latest Presto version. I would invite you to join the community Slack https://prestosql.io/slack.html > #troubleshooting so that we can talk interactively.